# git issue with remote branches changed after each fetch

Tags: git, corruption

I used `git fetch <remote> --depth=<N>` to get around a timeout issue adding a remote to my local repository.  Trying `git fetch <remote>` without specifying depth would time out.  So I tried `git fetch <remote> --depth=10` and then repeatedly `fetch`ed more and more, steadily increasing the depth each time, until I was finally able to get the whole thing (ie increasing depth retrieved zero objects).  After that I ran `git fetch <remote> --unshallow` which [is supposed to convert the remote back to a non-shallow remote copy](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch).

Here's my problem.  After doing all this, I'm not sure that my local repository is in the same/equivalent state that it would be if I had just done `git fetch <remote>` at the beginning, and it had not timed out.  Each time I `git fetch <remote>` it keeps reporting the same "new" and "updated" branches.

**What is happening, and how do I correct it?**

The only thing I can think of to try, that I haven't actually tried, is deleting the remote and adding it again.  I'm afraid of having to start over.  This is a very large repository and it took a long time to get to this point.  If I avoid `git gc` in the interim, will deleting and re-adding the remote allow the branches to reset without having to download all the commits again?

Here's what I have done and the results.

Every time I `git fetch <remote>` now, regardless of what I try, I get this output:

```
Fetching <remote>
From ssh://<url>
 + 3603285...775e0fe Feature/A -> <remote>/Feature/A  (forced update)
 + 6303337...de89a23 Feature/B -> <remote>/Feature/B  (forced update)
 * [new branch]      feature/C -> <remote>/feature/C
 * [new branch]      feature/D -> <remote>/feature/D
 * [new branch]      feature/E -> <remote>/feature/E
 * [new branch]      feature/F -> <remote>/feature/F
 * [new branch]      feature/G -> <remote>/feature/G
 * [new branch]      feature/H -> <remote>/feature/H
```

The same output every time.  Other remotes do not behave like this.  It appears with this remote only, the branch pointers are never actually getting advanced, and each `fetch` tries to advance them again.  There are never any actual errors in the output.

I have verified that these branches all do exist in the remote server and are not deleted there.  But, checking the entire commit history of branch `Feature/A` on the remote repo, it does not contain commit `3603285` at all.

Output of `git config --get remote.<remote>.fetch`:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/<remote>/*
```

Partial output of `git remote show <remote>`:

```
Remote branches:
  feature/X                        tracked
  feature/Y                        tracked
  feature/A                        tracked
  feature/B                        tracked
  refs/remotes/<remote>feature/C   stale (use 'git remote prune' to remove)
  refs/remotes/<remote>feature/D   stale (use 'git remote prune' to remove)
  refs/remotes/<remote>feature/E   stale (use 'git remote prune' to remove)
  refs/remotes/<remote>feature/F   stale (use 'git remote prune' to remove)
  refs/remotes/<remote>feature/G   stale (use 'git remote prune' to remove)
  refs/remotes/<remote>feature/H   stale (use 'git remote prune' to remove)
```

Things I have tried which did not correct this:

- `git fsck` (does not report any problems)
- `git fetch <remote> --unshallow` (reports the repository is already complete)
- `git gc` (no errors reported, running twice produces identical output)
- `git remote prune <remote>` (deletes branches `C` to `H`, but they are added back on next `fetch`)
- `git fetch --all --prune`

The output of `git fetch --all --prune` is a little different (also every time, regardless of what I try):

```
Fetching <remote>
From ssh://<url>
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> <remote>/Feature/C
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> <remote>/Feature/D
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> <remote>/Feature/E
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> <remote>/Feature/F
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> <remote>/Feature/G
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> <remote>/Feature/H
 + 3603285...775e0fe Feature/A -> <remote>/Feature/A  (forced update)
 + 6303337...de89a23 Feature/B -> <remote>/Feature/B  (forced update)
 * [new branch]      feature/C -> <remote>/feature/C
 * [new branch]      feature/D -> <remote>/feature/D
 * [new branch]      feature/E -> <remote>/feature/E
 * [new branch]      feature/F -> <remote>/feature/F
 * [new branch]      feature/G -> <remote>/feature/G
 * [new branch]      feature/H -> <remote>/feature/H
```

If I check out branch `<remote>/Feature/A` I get commit `3603285` not `775e0fe`, even though on the remote server, `Feature/A` points to `775e0fe` and `3603285` is nowhere in its history.  I can also check out `775e0fe` directly by commit string without issue.  This sequence of commands produces output that surprises me (also every time, regardless of what I try):

```
$ git checkout <remote>/Feature/A
HEAD is now at 3603285
$ git checkout -b Feature/A
$ git merge 775e0fe
Already up-to-date.
```

Comment: I have seen this sort of behavior before, on systems with case-folding. I see you have both `feature/<name>` and `Feature/<name>` here, with lowercase and uppercase F. If this is the same problem, that's what it is. Your Git thinks it must destroy the wrong-case branch and create the right-case branch, which it does, but then you still have the wrong-case names because your OS folds case and writes everything into the existing other-case directory. The solution is to use an OS (or file system) that does not fold case, or fix the upstream to use a single case.

Comment: @torek This is exactly right.  The remote repo contains upper and lowercase versions of `Feature/A` and `Feature/B` with different commits.  And all the `[deleted]` branches are pruned as `Feature/...` and then added back as `feature/...` in lower case.  Add your solution and as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a file system case-folding problem, so it has nothing to do with the shallow part (which is sort of good news / bad news).

I see you have both `feature/<name>` and `Feature/<name>` here, with lowercase and uppercase F.  Your Git sets these up in your repository, but once it creates a directory with one case, the branch names with the other case go in the same directory.  Your Git then thinks those are wrong: it must destroy the wrong-case branch and create the right-case branch, which it does, but then you still have the wrong-case names because your OS once again folds case and writes everything into the existing other-case directory.

The usual solution is to use an OS (or file system) that does not fold case, or fix the upstream to use a single case.

If that's not possible, I have an idea that I have never tested, but should work: you can split up your `fetch` URL.  This has various drawbacks, the main one being that you must manually run `git ls-remote` occasionally and check to see if you need to update your URL mappings.  (It's far better to use one of the more usual solutions.)

Comment: Bingo!  I am using Windows and the remote is almost certainly Linux, and descending into the `.git` folder I can see exactly what you describe.  Also the remote does indeed have two branches `Feature/A` and `feature/A` etc.  So this is almost certainly the correct explanation.  Now that I know my local repo is not corrupted, in my case I can safely ignore these branches, so I will leave the attempt of your split fetch solution to someone else.